# Keep focus after insertHtml with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I made a simple plugin to insert HTML into an inline CKEditor. But after every insert, the editor loses focus. Is there a way to keep focus and keep the cursor active after inserting the HTML?

```
editor
    .addCommand("InsertHtml",
    {
        exec: function ()
        {
            editor.insertHtml("<span>xxx</span>");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `insertElement` instead of `insertHtml` the focus is kept.

```
var newElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<span>xxx</span>", editor.document);

editor.insertElement(newElement);
```

Comment: Hello @Adrian, I have used insertHtml method but problem is data doesn't get inserted on IE if I don't have focus set within editor. Any idea how it should be for IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to dynamically put focus back on the editor with javascript using the `.focus()` function on the editor `input`.

```
editor.addCommand("InsertHtml",
       {
           exec: function () {
               editor.insertHtml("<span>xxx</span>");
               document.getElementById("yourCKEditorInputId").focus();
           }
       });
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. My editor is an inline contenteditable. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Hmm so its the HMTLElement that you are editing which requires the focus and not the actual editor. Does the editor dissapear when losing focus or is the actual HTMLElement just not showing the cursor?

Comment: Found it! Posted as answer.